# Partial fit . Обучение по частям в Scikit,

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, big-data

Всем привет!

Я обучаю ML модель на Scikit, обучение проводится на нескольких миллионах текстовых данных. После того, как я готовлю данные к обучению, чищу, нормализую и векторизую, их объем достигает почти 100 гигабайт выборки Вопрос(вектор)-Ответ. У меня нет настолько мощного сервера, по этому я столкнулся с нуждой обучения модели по частям, и нашел в Scikit Partial fit, но на модели которые мне нужны, нужно передать параметр classes, он должен содержать в себе все возможные вариации ответов.

В итоге classes.shape = (646772, 176902), где каждый символ это float 64. На сколько сильно я не хотел бы оптимизировать решения, я не понимаю как я могу обучить модель на своих текстовых данных, ведь мне в любом случае не хватает оперативной памяти, ведь её требуется 700 гигабайт.
И вопрос: что я могу сделать в данной ситуации, что бы обучить модель?
Может есть другой способ обучения по частям, но без classes?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Удалось что-то сделать, помог ли мой ответ, остались ли вопросы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это зависит от того, какие методы маш. обучения вы используете и как вы готовите данные. В частности, можно при обработке просто отбросить редко используемые слова. Но главное - использовать **разреженные матрицы**, есть довольно много методов в `Scikit Learn`, которые их понимают. В частности `HashingVectorizer` и `MultinomialNB` умеют создавать/принимать разреженные матрицы соответственно. Причём, `HashingVectorizer` ещё и `stateless`, т.е. его можно спокойно использовать на порциях любого размера, он не сохраняет своё состояние, ему это не нужно. Ну и далее по пайплайну для построения модели можно использовать какую-нибудь дообучаемую модель (навскидку я их не помню, к сожалению). Т.е. можно просто в цикле, насколько у вас есть памяти брать кусочек данных, прогонять его через `HashingVectorizer` и дообучать на получившихся обработанных данных модель. И так по кругу, пока все данные не используете.
С разреженными матрицами главное не сделать их обратно плотными на каком-то этапе обработки данных, а то у вас внезапно опять память кончится.